# Highchart stacked area empty spaces (negative values)

Tags: highcharts

I have stacked areas where one is below zero. My problem is that on the graph there are empty spaces
[image: Empty spaces]

My series values:

```
series: [{
                fillColor: '#FF3F3F',
                name: 'Alarm',
                data: [500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500]
            },
{
                fillColor: '#FFFF14',
                name: 'Middle',
                data: [100, 400, 150, 150, 200, 200, 250]
            }, 
            {
                fillColor: '#78C43A',
                name: 'Target',             
                data: [-300, 100, 150, -150, 200, -200, 250]
            },...
```

By the way - how to fill the bottom of chart with green area (and analogously red area till y axis max)?

Comment: Based on my analysis of `highcharts.src.js`, it looks like you've found a bug (somewhere around [line 12424 of the file](http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js)). Your best bet would be to file a bug [on their bug tracker](http://highcharts.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic).

Comment: That's the bugtracker of Highcharts.net, which is just a wrapper. Highcharts JS's tracker is at https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues

Comment: This is the same issue: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1059

Comment: Yes, thanks for the link :) Any idea about when solution could be delivered?

Comment: see if this workaround helps https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8517#issuecomment-399516509

Answer (score 1):

with latest highcharts (3.0+), this issue can be solved. the gap has come because the threshold for the area chart is zero. change the threshold to the least value in the chart and try.

you can set threshold at

```
plotOptions: {
areac: {
threshold: -5//i've take -5 as example
}
}
```

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/kgnHu/) is what you want I guess